# How to draw new line by KineticJS based on mixed JavaScript canvas code?

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs

The exist code is as follow:

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
  container: 'container',
  width: 578,
  height: 200
});
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
stage.add(layer);
document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0].id='myCanvas';
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
canvas.width=578;
canvas.height=200;
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(100, 150);
context.lineTo(450, 50);
context.stroke();
```

Now I have to use KineticJS to draw new shape, when I added 'this.layer.draw()' method, the exsited shape has gone.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/walkingp/DJc5t/)

Answer (score 1):

After I added this line, it works well.

```
layer.setClearBeforeDraw(false);
```

[Changed code](http://jsfiddle.net/walkingp/DJc5t/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Working code

```
        var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
      container: 'container',
      width: 578,
      height: 200
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    layer.setClearBeforeDraw(false);
    stage.add(layer);

    document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0].id='myCanvas';
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    canvas.width=578;
    canvas.height=200;
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(100, 150);
    context.lineTo(450, 50);
    context.stroke();

    /* how to draw line by using Kinetic? */
    var redLine = new Kinetic.Line({
        points: [73, 70, 340, 23, 450, 60, 500, 20],
        stroke: 'red',
        strokeWidth: 1,
        lineCap: 'round',
        lineJoin: 'round'
    });
    layer.add(redLine);
    layer.draw();
```

Comment: Your fiddle works, but in my codes, the codes between line 1 and line 15 can't be changed. Then I have to use KineticJS to draw a new line. Do you have any good idea?

Comment: It worked after I added this line.
layer.setClearBeforeDraw(false);